# How to calculate polygon's component/projection/intercept length along a line in ArcGIS pro?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro

This is not a hard to do manually but is there any process to get the value using attribute table?

The picture shows 3 polygons and a line. I want the component/projection/intercept length of these polygons along the line.

I'm new to coding. I don't know if this problem requires coding or not.

If you are new to the term component please see here, https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/component-vector-.html

[image]

Comment: I dont understand what you want to calculate. Can you draw some arrows etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, but it requires coding. Here is the pseudo code for such an algorithm:

```
For each polygon
  For each line segment on the perimeter of the polygon
    For each vertex on that segment
      Find the nearest point A on the road vector from the vertex
      Find the nearest point B on the road vector for the next vertex
      Draw a line from A to B as the projection onto the road vector
      Save that line as new geometry to some layer
    Next vertex    
  Next segment
  Once all segments for a polygon are projected, 
     merge into one projection for the entire polygon
Next polygon
```